# Creating an external Label for the goto function to work across source files

Tags: c, codeblocks

Hey guys I have a brief question that probably has an even briefer answer. I've done some digging cant seem to find an answer. I've recently returned to programming(C in Code:Blocks/GNU GCC compiler) and can't for the life of me remember how to use the "goto" statement to return to a label across a module. Here is my Code so far.

P.S. All the files are in the same project, in the same source code folder. I will be extending this program I am first creating the frame that code will work in because the rest is literally copy and paste and just change the question and the answer.

---

### main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void second(void);
void third(void);


int question = 0;
int Ans = 0;

int main()
{
    system("COLOR FC");
    printf("This program is testing a method of linking modules.\n");
    printf("For this purpose the two topics chosen are maths and science.\n\n");
    printf("Would you like to choose maths or science?\n");
    printf("1. Science\n");
    printf("2. Maths\n\n");

//Responding to the first input

    scanf("%d",&question);
    if(question==1)
    {
         second();
    }
    if(question==2)
    {
         third();
    }
  //When the first input has been desired and the module has been completed.
  //This is where i wish to return.
goto Ending;

  //Ending the Program
Ending:
{
    system("cls"); 
    printf("The program will now exit.\n");
    system("pause");
}


   return 0;
   }
```

---

### second.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>


void second(void)
{
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
    system("COLOR E5");
    printf("Here is the Science Module\n");



    system("pause");
    return main();
    //I WANT TO RETURN TO THE LABEL:ENDING; FROM HERE
 }
```

---

### third.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>


void third(void)
{
     system("pause");
     system("cls");
     system("COLOR A4");
     printf("Here is the Maths Module.\n");

     system("pause");
     return main();
     //I WANT TO RETURN TO THE LABEL:ENDING; FROM HERE
 }
```

If someone can shed some light as to what I need to do that will be thanked heaps.

Comment: `goto` can only transfer control witin a function. There's no such thing as inter-function or inter-module `goto`. There's `setjmp/longjmp`, but it is a library-level functionality with a significantly different semantics.

Comment: is there another way i can go to that specific part of the program then, like return to the main source and when i return to the main source go straight to the action of ending the program???

Comment: You may be interested in the `exit` library function.

Comment: tl;dr, but that sounds like an XY-problem and a very bad design. Briefly: **DON'T** "If someone can shed some light as to what I need to do that will be thanked heaps." - No offence, but the best would be to revisit structured and modular programming basics.

Answer (score 2):

You can't goto a label outside your function. Furthermore, your program is recursively calling main() which is almost certainly a bad thing.

Edit: if you want to return to the labeled spot, just return.

Comment: I might actually just create another source file which is the Ending and just send it to that, it will probs be alot easier but i would still like to see an example of another way to achieve this private message me the example if you want

Comment: Recursively calling `main` is legal in C.

Comment: Not doing it does not make the code any better. Heck, `goto` cross-module is sooo very 70/80ies BASIC

Comment: In this case, calling main recursively means the code won't do what the asker wants.